# React Read Child State

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an app and I decided to create two components: `<AddReport />` and `<ListOfClients />`. In the first one, it handles all the functions with adding a report. In ListOfClients it basically provides the list of clients of a company and ideally, allows to choose and click. Then it would pass the ID of the client to AddReport so the user can add report to the chosen client's account.

```
class AddReport extends Component {
  state = {
    client: ''
  }

  addReportHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const managerUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const managerName = fire.auth().currentUser.Name + ' ' + fire.auth().currentUser.Surname;
    const currentDate = new Date().getTime();
      fire.database().ref('clients/' + clientID + '/Reports/').push({
        content: this.rContent.value,
        date: currentDate,
        manager: 'Manager',
        managerID: managerUID
      });
    }

 selectClient(e){
      this.setState({client: ''});
    }
  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.addReportHandler.bind(this)}>
      <ListOfClients clicked={this.selectClient.bind(this)}/>
      <textarea className="form-control" placeholder="Content" ref={ el => this.rContent = el } />
      <button className="btn btn-primary">Add Report</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

`<ListOfClients />` looks like that in the render method (everything works fine with retrieving he client list

```
render()
  {
  let clientList = this.state.clientList.map( client =>
    <a key={client.Id} onClick={this.props.clicked} class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{client.name}</a>
  );
  console.log(clientList);
  let placeholder = 'Search for ' + this.state.companyName + ' clients';
  return (
    <div>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder={placeholder}  />
    <div className="list-group">
    {clientList}
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: what is your question exactly what do you want us to help you with

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions to automatically bind `this`:

```
class AddReport extends Component {
  selectClient = (client) => {
    this.setState({ client });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <form>
        <ListOfClients clicked={this.selectClient}/>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Send `client` in the callback function:

```
<a key={client.Id} onClick={() => this.props.clicked(client)} class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{client.name}</a>
```